# Data structure for state modification in backtracking

Tags: haskell

I am writing my first larger Haskell program. The resulting application must allocate resources under a set of constraints. The algorithmic approach is brute force, since allocating a resource for each of the tasks is dependent on previous allocations. This is basically backtracking with constraint checking after each allocation. I am now considering what data structures I should use to make this as efficient as possible.

The output (value) of the program is the list of resource allocations. The set of resources available is handled as a state using the `StateT` monad transformer. The state is a container of containers of containers: container of people, each having a container of days, each having a container of allocated times (pre-allocated before the program has started, or allocated by the program).

During the search for a feasible solution the containers at the lowest level (allocated times) will be modified when a task is assigned to a specific person on a specific day at a specific time. Given that the search is likely to backtrack a large number of times, this will result in a large number of "copies" of immutable data. To be more specific, during each state change, exactly one item will be added to exactly one container at the lowest level: one time on a specific day will be allocated to a specific person. My question is:

*Which data structure(s) should I use given the large number of copies of immutable data?*

Comment: Can you encode the problem as a SAT or SMT problem? There is some crazy levels of clever in solvers these days, and it would completely sidestep your data structures question. Anyway I think you're overestimating the cost of copies. GHC (and generational garbage collection in general) is amazing at handling frequent, short-lived allocations.

Comment: I have not evaluated the SAT or SMT approach, as I have never done them. The problem involves time intervals (and checking for their overlaps and separations in time) along with daily total work quotas and rest breaks. I have a feeling that the Haskell solution will be complete long before I would have this coded in first-order logic with the temporal stuff in the mix.

Comment: I don't think there's enough detail here to give a good/interesting answer. Can you provide some code that represents your problem? I appreciate the intent behind the question you're asking, but tend to agree with Daniel Wagner that it would be best for you to implement the solution that seems most natural and measure and optimize later if it doesn't perform the way you like

Comment: Perhaps the backtracking monad is an option: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-lgbt-0.0.2/docs/Control-Monad-Backtrack.html

Comment: @jhu Sounds perfect for SMT (with the theory of integers to represent time) to me. And to be clear, I'm not proposing you code directly in first-order logic. You should absolutely still use Haskell to represent the problem inputs, and write a Haskell program to produce the SMT query/interpret its results. I don't think you'll be able to code up a solver for your problem faster than you can transform it into an `SBool` from sbv, say, and ship it off to a solver.

Comment: Have you tried just using `Data.Map`?

Comment: The reason I am not too eager to start exploring SMT is that I actually _already wrote_ a working, backtracking solver using `StateT` for this, one that I have tested with small toy data. In the current version I am using lists as data structures all along. I am just wondering, before I start applying the solver to real data, what the performance will be. But maybe I will do what some suggested: take the straightforward route and optimize later if need be. Or even turn to SMT if necessary. The boring stuff (parsing etc.) I need to do next won't be wasted in any case. Thanks.